# Adding XY Points to ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, xy

I am trying to import an Excel table with around 10,000 XY points into ArcMap 10.2. I am using State Plane NAD 1983 Alabama West (US Feet) as the Coordinate System in my map data frame. I then add the excel table to my Table of Contents in the map then select Display XY Data. Next, I choose the same coordinate system as my data frame then select OK. Once it creates the Events layer for my points they are not in the correct location.

Should I switch everything in my map to WGS84 or is there a solution for my points to be added onto my current map with the state plane coordinate system?

[image: XY Points in Excel]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

These data are in longitude and latitude, I would set your data frame to a geographic coordinate system WGS84, save the file to another format (ie shapefile) and use the Define Projection tool to establish its coordinate system...then use it

Answer (score 5):

I think I see what is happening here. If you are in North America (and I think using State Plane for Alabama indicates that you are). You have your x and y switched in your spreadsheet. Latitude (Y) is going to be in the 33 range and Longitude (X) is going to be a negative number (-87 +/-).

I see also what Dan is saying. I would probably handle this by defining the coordinate system as Geographic since you already using Lat/Longs and then project it to State Plane (if necessary).

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that your data is in wgs84 or another projection, but by entering the state plane projection into the event layer dialog, you are telling arcgis that your input data is in state plane already. you would need to set the coordinate system of the input to the correct one, and then convert it to state plane.